# What should I do if the radio and micro receiver don't run on the same protocol?

Tags: quadcopters, flight-controller, esc-protocol

I recently got started on FPV and I got a cheap Tyro 69 toothpick and a Flysky fs-i6 radio, but the micro receiver won't bind to the radio, should I get another micro receiver that run on ibus, or buy a better radio?

Comment: Could you specify which type of micro receiver you have so that it's possible to determine which radios it will be compatible with?

Comment: Multiprotocol radios are great for this. Namely (not a product recommendation, that's not my intent) the jumper t-16 or the radiomaster tx16s. Multiprotocol modules are also available. If you're going to take this hobby more seriously, a good, reliable radio (remember, it doesn't crash and burn, so spend good money on it) is a wonderful investment